# Vertical and Horizontal alignment of text with CSS

Tags: css, html, alignment, center

I'm trying to align a text, horizontally and vertically, inside a div box (with background color) but I'm not being able to do it.

I've searched online and `margin: auto`, `text-align: center` aren't doing the work.

Any tips?

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mBBJM/1/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="services"><div class="holder container clearfix">
<div class="bgtop"><span class="top">Corte cabelo + Afiar</span></div>
<div class="bgprice"><span class="price">10€</span></div>
</div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#services .holder .bgtop{
    background-color: #27ae60;
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#services .holder .bgprice{
    height:50px;
    width:90px;
    background-color: #272727;
    z-index: 1;
}
#services .holder span.top{
    color: white;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.000em;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;  
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#services .holder span.price{
    color: white;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.500em;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change just your CSS to this (no HTML changes):

```
div{
  background: red;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

The `text-align` is self-explanatory.  The `line-height` forces the text to the center by matching the height of a single line to that of the div. You will have to adjust it to your needs each time.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azuckerman/mBBJM/3411/)

Comment: Can you edit to the way I have on the fiddle example? Im not getting it right, so it has no effect...

Comment: Sure, this works, but what if the height of the element is dynamic?

Comment: Things become a little more difficult. If you can change the HTML, then it makes sense to do what is shown in the other answers (e.g., display: table-cell;). You can also use javascript to set the line-height based on its container. There are other techniques that work in specific browsers, but do not work across the board. You will have to find all of the CSS hacks to make it work.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a common approach used for vertical/horizontal centering.

[**BASIC EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yd8m3/)

```
div {
    background: red;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    display:table;
}
div > span {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Basically, the parent element's display is changed to `table`. Add in a child element, in this case a `span` element to wrap the text. The `span` should have the properties `display:table-cell`/`vertical-align:middle` for vertical centering. Then `text-align:center` is simply for horizontal centering.

Here is [**an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/SyQe7/) using the styling you had.

Comment: I've seen that aproach and I've tried but its not working for me

Comment: @uniqezor Did you look at the example? It works.. http://jsfiddle.net/SyQe7/

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways. Here is one:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span>magix!</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    text-align:center;
    display:table;
}
span { 
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBBJM/3410/)