# Make text appear at the center of the SPAN horizontally and vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to render some text in a DIV which should appear at the center of the SPAN - both vertically as well as horizontally.

This is my jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8Syqv/13/

HTML:

```
 <span>something here</span>
```

CSS:

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
}

```
span {
position: absolute;
border: 1px red solid;
height: 30%;
width: 40%;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
top: 0;
right: 0;

}
```

I have looked at these:

[Vertical and Horizontal alignment of text with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394526/vertical-and-horizontal-alignment-of-text-with-css)

[How to center an element horizontally and vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically)

and more..

But, the ideas suggested here did not work on my jsfiddle.
I think m missing something here. not sure what>

Thank You

Comment: Are you assuming you have to set the height of the element? Whether in px or percentage?

Comment: does the span have to be `position: absolute;`?

Comment: Percentage. This percentage is also being calculated on the fly based on the width and height of parent element and sibling elements. So, it is never fixed.

Comment: No, actually it has position relative. But, I tried position absolute after looking at other jsfiddle examples in stackoverflow with similar problems. So, you can scratch that

Comment: Why set a height if you want the content to be centered? Why not just give it a top and bottom padding and be done? http://jsfiddle.net/AWU77/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may changes the HTML you wrote your question around. But i guess, this will help you anyways:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8Syqv/39/

(altered) HTML

```
<div>
    <span>something here</span>
</div>
```

Some CSS

```
body 
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
}

div
{
   border: 1px red solid;
   height: 30%;
   width: 40%;  
   text-align: center;
   left: 0;
   margin: auto;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   position: absolute;
}

span 
{  
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div:after
{
   display: inline-block; 
   vertical-align: middle; 
   height: 100%;
   content:"";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. However, I have to keep minimal number of HTML nodes in my app. So, if you come across any solution that does not require a wrapper will be great appreciated. :) thank you

Comment: Yeah, you are right,the text kinda get carried away if it is too much :P See this --- http://jsfiddle.net/8Syqv/36/

Comment: I got carried aways with my thoughts also ... I'll call it a day ;) Answer updated...

Comment: Thanks for your help though :) I really appreciate it

Comment: your welcome. Have fun.