# How to align SPAN inside a DIV vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="slideClick">
    <div style="padding: 0; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center; border: 1px solid blue;">
        <span class="sideMsg">MESSAGES</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sideMsg
{
        color:#333;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
    bottom:0;
    font-family: ‘Trebuchet MS’, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #333;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#slideClick {
    float:left;
    height:90px;
    width:40px;
    background:#EE8D40;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Displays this:

[image]

How can I center the `SPAN` horizontally and vertically inside the blue `DIV`?

Comment: This is one of the most answered questions on SO.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577730/vertical-align-span-inside-div  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421334/vertical-and-horizontal-align-middle-and-center-with-css

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394526/vertical-and-horizontal-alignment-of-text-with-css

Comment: @TylerH **NO** this is different. OP wants to align the transformed element and not the regular flow element.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge your approach is incorrect. You should transform your whole element and not just the text.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Sure it is. Just do as you said; align it first then transform the whole thing. http://jsfiddle.net/89eu7xvv/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pauldic/zfuLzonp/) Which could be what you want

```
<div id="slideClick">
    <div>
        <span class="sideMsg">MESSAGES</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pauldic/zfuLzonp/) Which could be what you want

```
<div id="slideClick">
    <div>
        <span class="sideMsg">MESSAGES</span>
    </div>
</div>


.sideMsg
{
        color:#333;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
    bottom:0;
    font-family: ‘Trebuchet MS’, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #333;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#slideClick {
    float:left;
    height:190px;
    width:200px;
    background:#EE8D40;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it also compatible with IE8 and IE9?

Comment: Yes it should be, but you will need crosscheck that, I dont have a windows pc to test that but I have included -ms-..... to take care of IE

Comment: Alright, I will like to know about your test result

Comment: I Upvoted for now :)

Comment: Although it is a lot of CSS code but I was able to tweak your code a bit and make it work. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, where you able to test for the IE? I might setup a Windows Virtual Box for windows related testing. Congrats anyways :)

Comment: It is working... 95% of the way for IE but no biggie. It is a small issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

AS stated above this is a common problem in CSS, hovever i see the tricky part when you're rotating only the text span. Rotate the wrapper element and from there centering should be pie.

```
#slideClick{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

For example with line-height since height is set.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1vnbyL1t/3/

Answer (score 1):

Since your div has a fixed size, you can use a relative position for the inner span :

```
position:relative;
top:35px;
right:17px;
```

and just adjust it accordingly : http://jsfiddle.net/38dgooxj/2/

Comment: I adjusted my code to match yours but for some reason the text is outside of the orange box in IE8 :/

Comment: Try `left:10px` instead of right, and if it is not working, continue making changes until it does :)

Comment: Thank you. I upvoted for now :)